# C Program Compiled with Cygwin and Called from Python Hangs

Tags: python, c, dll, cygwin

I'm trying to call a c program from Python using `ctypes`. I've got a minimum (non-)working example below.

#### C Program

Here is the C program I'm trying to call into. Just your standard hello world program. I compile this, on windows, using eclipse and the cygwin gcc compiler to produce a `.dll` file.

**main.h**

```
#ifndef INC_MAIN_H_
#define INC_MAIN_H_

void helloWorld();

unsigned char buf[] = "Hello World!";

#endif /* INC_MAIN_H_ */
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"

void helloWorld(){
    printf("\n%s\n\n", buf);
}
```

#### Python Program

Then I write a python script to load my `.dll` and call the `helloWorld` function. Importantly, I do pull over both the `.dll` I created and the `cygwin1.dll`.

**helloWorld.py**

```
from ctypes import CDLL
import os

def loadDLL(file):
    file = file.replace('\\','/')
    if not os.path.exists(file):
        raise FileNotFoundError(file)

    print('Opening DLL File:', file)
    dll = CDLL(file)

    return dll

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dll = loadDLL(FILE_TO_LOAD)
    dll.helloWorld()
```

When I go to run this program, `loadDLL` works just fine and loads the DLL. However, calling the `helloWorld` function from the c program causes it to hang.

Oddly enough, if I replace the `printf` line with something innocuous (e.g., `int x = 0`), it executes fine but prints out a seemingly random number.

Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong? Or even a way to figure out what's going wrong?

Btw, I was able to get a nearly identical setup to work just fine on a linux system, so I'm guessing it's due to the windows environment that I've setup, but I couldn't begin to guess what it really is.

**UPDATE**

I'm not writing this as an answer because it doesn't solve the letter of the problem, but only the spirit.

At [Jean-Francois Fabre's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327774/c-program-compiled-with-cygwin-and-called-from-python-hangs#comment79616658_46327774) I dropped cygwin for mingw and things now work as expected. Apparently cygwin works in strange ways. [Ahmed Masud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327774/c-program-compiled-with-cygwin-and-called-from-python-hangs#comment79617568_46327774) was able to find [a useful link](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html) about how cygwin programs should be compiled if they're to be used for external libraries, but that seemed like much more trouble that just using mingw (not to mention the other problems I'd already encountered trying to use cygwin for this).

FWIW, this program must also be run in on the command line in order to see the output of the c program. Running in python's IDLE did not capture the `printf` output from the c program.

Comment: personally I'd drop cygwin for MinGW if you can do that...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Why do you suggest that?

Comment: try replacing your `printf` with `fprintf (stderr, "\n%s\n\n", buf);` and share what happens.

Comment: @AhmedMasud No dice, it still hangs. I suspect something is wrong with my environment or the way I compile. As I said, replacing the `printf` with something like `int x = 0;` causes the function to run without hanging, but then I get a random number printed out and I've no idea where that number is coming from or why it's being printed.

Comment: One more thing, move your `unsigned char buf[] = "Hello World"` to the `main.c` file, and declare it `static unsigned char buf[]` to make it local. Let's see if that fixes things. I highly doubt that your environment is to blame.

Comment: Because cygwin works in strange ways

Comment: @AhmedMasud Sorry, still doesn't work... I can't believe it has anything to do with the c program itself because, as I said, I got it working on a linux system no problem. I suspect, as Jean-Fracois seems to, that it is something to do with cygwin.

Comment: hmm hey he may be right :P

Comment: Aaah found something .... https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html apparently cygwin has a weirdness w.r.t. dlls. MinGW DLLs work as standard windows DLLs whereas they need fiddling (read the bottom of the page) to work with cygwin.

Comment: Could it be that your C program isn't returning anything?

Comment: @AhmedMasud Nice find. That looks promising. I'll take a look and see if that solves my problem.

Comment: The problem is that you are calling a cywgin program from a NOT cygwin python and having the wrong expectation. cygwin programs have different paradigma than normal windows programs.

Comment: @matzeri That was the problem. Once I ran the python script from the cygwin terminal using the cygwin installed python, it worked. If you want to put this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling a cywgin program from a NOT cygwin python and having the wrong expectation.

cygwin programs have different paradigma (Posix-like) than normal windows programs.

It is recommended to test with both cygwin python and compiler, or both windows one.

Comment: For future users, I was indeed using a personal install of Python and not Cygwin's install of Python. Once I switched, it worked as expected.