# How can I run a binary via Cygwin64 from cmd.exe with access to STDOUT/STDERR

Tags: python, cmd, cygwin

I want to run CDO, which provides a Cygwin64 compiled Windows binary, from the Windows cmd.exe.

I have already found that I can run `c:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe c:/path/to/cdo.exe`, which does in principle work.  However, I would like to have access to the `cdo` process's  STDOUT/STDERR.  So I guess what I'm looking for is a "cygwin-runner" kind of thing, which allows me to run a cygwin-compiled binary from Windows `cmd.exe` and still interact with STDOUT and STDERR.

The motivation is to do something like this in Python:

```
path2cdo = 'c:\\cygwin64\\bin\\CYGWIN_RUNNER c:/path/to/cdo.exe'
proc = subprocess.Popen([path2cdo,'-V'],stderr = subprocess.PIPE,stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

I guess I could also just run the `python.exe` process from within Cygwin, but if possible I'd like to avoid that.

**UPDATE:** I would like my module to work with the regular Anaconda Python interpreter, so that a user can just `conda install mypackage` and then, provided that Cygwin is installed, work with it.  So using the Cygwin Python is not an option.

Comment: have you tried the cygwin version of python ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @matzeri but that's not really an option for me, see updated question.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327774/c-program-compiled-with-cygwin-and-called-from-python-hangs