# calling function hangs after loading DLL using Ctypes in Windows

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, dll, ctypes

I am doing a simple test in **Windows 10** to test calling a DLL compiled from a c code using `Ctypes` in `64 bit Python 3.7`. My problem is that after loading the DLL, calling a function just hangs there eternally. Here are my codes:

**c_dll.h**

```
__declspec(dllexport) void hello_world(void);
```

**c_dll.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "c_dll.h"
// I also tested delete __declspec(dllexport), and it did not help
__declspec(dllexport) void hello_world(){
    printf("hello world\n");
}
```

The above code is compiled to a 64-bit shared library `libdll.dll` using `gcc`, which is installed in **CygWin**. I executed the below compile code in a bash file in cmd prompt:

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic c_dll.c
gcc -shared -o libdll.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libdll.lib c_dll.o
```

Then, I created a `test.py` to call the DLL. Note that DLL is located in the same folder as `test.py`

**test.py**

```
from ctypes import *
lib=CDLL("libdll.dll") # I also tested absolute path and it wont work
print(vars(lib))
lib.hello_world()
```

When I looked at the print out, which is as follows, it looks like loading DLL is successful. It is interesting to note that if I executed the `test.py` mutiple times, the print-out in was blank few times. Even in the execution the below print-out was occured, calling the function `hellow_world` hung there forever. As a last note, I tried to carry out the above process in Ubuntu, it was successful.

```
{'_name': 'libdll.dll', '_FuncPtr': <class 'ctypes.CDLL.__init__.<locals>._FuncPtr'>, '_handle': 19994312704}
```

Can you please advise or comment? Thank you.

P.S.

- Per Jean-François Fabre has commented, I changed `lib.hello_world(None)` to `lib.hello_world()`. It won't solve the problem I had.

Comment: no arguments: don't pass `None`. I use to declare the function beforehand with arguments bTW

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre 1) I tested again after deleting `None` and it did not help. 2) do you mean doing something like `lib.hello_world.argtypes=...`?

Comment: yes, I mean exactly that.

Comment: BTW are you sure your compiler produces 64 bit DLLs? I've done that stunt a lot of times (python + C++ DLL with C interface) and it works fine

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I tried doing `gcc -m64`, which I believe can generate 64 bit DLL. But, I am not 100% sure. Let me search how I can check if a DLL is 64 bit or 32 bit.

Comment: best way is to download a real 64-bit gcc compiler.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I checked my DLL and it is 64-bit.

Comment: have you tried with older versions? I tested your code with python 3.4 and 3.6 and it worked fine. in which shell are you running it? command prompt? IDE?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for testing the code, and yes, I use command prompt to run the python script. I am wondering: 1) whether GCC in CygWin would cause any problem? 2) I tested using a C code to call the DLL, and it worked fine. I haven't tried the old versions yet. This might not be the problem, as I tested in Linux with Python 3.7 and it worked fine.

Comment: cygwin hell yes!! use a native gcc compiler instead

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Will try using a native gcc compiler and let you know shortly. Thank you.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I ran the whole thing in CygWin with successes. It looks like we found the problem. Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327774/c-program-compiled-with-cygwin-and-called-from-python-hangs) and I saw your comments there:)

Comment: yes I am all over the place :) didn't even remember that. Closing as duplicate then :)